# XMLHttpRequest sort data without additional request

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I'm using a standard `XMLHttpRequest` to fetch some JSON data from an API. Initially I am displaying all of the data (unfiltered). When ever a button is clicked I want to sort by that specific `genre`.

How can I sort through the data on user click without re-requesting the data every time? Unless I'm mistaken, you can't store the returned data in a global variable? Would it be best to sort it in local data?

**app.js**

```
// Get data from API
makeRequest(url)
.then(function (data) {
  // Render ALL data from API
  renderData(data);
})
```

**index.html**

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" onclick="sortByGenre('rock')">Rock</button>
```

**JSON data**

```
[{
  "date": {
    "dayOfWeek": "Thursday",
    "month": "Oct"
  },
  "location": "Bristol",
  "genre": "rock"
}, {
  "date": {
    "dayOfWeek": "Cardiff",
    "dayOfMonth": 13,
    "month": "Oct"
  },
  "location": "Manchester",
  "genre": "jazz"
}]
```

Thank you

Comment: Store it to a variable and read it.... Seems like you already knew it.

Comment: @epascarello - For some reason I had it in my head that you couldn't assign the returned data to a variable.

Comment: You probably were thinking of it that you try to read it before the data has been fetched. Your case you should know the data has been fetched so it should be available to read. You could use promises if you are worried.

Comment: @epascarello I had never thought that was why you couldn't store it as a variable. Thank you. If you add this as a response I'll accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just store the returned data into a variable - it wouldn't require an additional request.